# pyparsing optional elements leads to wrong value for asDict method

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

For the following code,

```
import pyparsing as pp

n1 = pp.Regex(r'N1*(.*?)\~').setResultsName("name")
n2 = pp.Optional(pp.Regex(r'N2*(.*?)\~').setResultsName("add_name"))
n3 = pp.Regex(r'N3*(.*?)\~').setResultsName("add")
n4 = pp.Optional(pp.Regex(r'N4*(.*?)\~').setResultsName("geo"))
name_and_address = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4
```

I am expecting that the key add_name wont have any value for the string:

```
"N1*SF*XYZ corp SMP Unpaid BU*25*666666~N3*What ever st~N4*NEW ALBANY*OH*430549263*US~"
```

as in

```
name_and_address.parseString("N1*SF*XYZ corp SMP Unpaid BU*25*666666~N3*What ever st~N4*NEW ALBANY*OH*430549263*US~").asDict()
```

would have

```
{'geo': 'N4*NEW ALBANY*OH*430549263*US~',
 'add': 'N3*What ever st~',
 'name': 'N1*SF*XYZ corp SMP Unpaid BU*25*666666~'}
```

However, the actual output is

```
name_and_address.parseString("N1*SF*XYZ corp SMP Unpaid BU*25*666666~N3*What ever st~N4*NEW ALBANY*OH*430549263*US~").asDict()
{'add': 'N3*8100SMITHSMILLRD~',
 'add_name': 'N2*8100SMITHSMILLRD~',
 'name': 'N1*SF*Hollister SMP Unpaid BU*25*823871341~'}
```

The key "add" has value of string that begins with N3 than N2.

Comment: In n1's Regex, `r'N1*(.*?)\~'` should be  `r'N1\*(.*?)\~'`; and similar for n2, n3, and n4.

Comment: Haha. That's it. Thanks !!